# Ruby on Rails update existing line item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations

I've constructed an ecommerce website of sorts using models and associations.

Between the cart model (unique to each user) and product model (various products with a quantity field) I have a Line Item model which generates a record each time a user adds a product and desired quantity. The newly generated Line Item is then associated with a cart_ID specific to the user that is currently in session.

The problem i'm currently facing is when a user tries to add more of an existing product to their cart. As my code currently stands a new line item is generated each time the user adds the same product, even if the product being added already has a Line Item that was previously generated.

How can I modify my forms code to identify whether an existing line item contains the product being added and updating that line items quantity, rather than creating a new line item. I'm guessing it contains some sort of IF logic and modification to the Line Item controller, however I am what they call a noob.

```
<%= form_for [@product, LineItem.new] do |f|%>
<%= f.label :quantity %>
<%= f.text_field :quantity, class:"form-control" %>
<%= f.submit 'Add' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller:

```
if params[:line_item_id].present?
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:line_item_id])
else
  @line_item = LineItem.new
end
```

and change `LineItem.new` to `@line_item` in your view.

Obviously, you'll want to ensure that the user has access to said line item — whether that's through their cart/order/whatever.

Of note, Rails will take care of pointing the form to the update action of your controller as well if it's an existing LineItem, or to Create if it's a new LineItem.

Comment: Should note, you can also use `LineItem.find_or_initialize_by(id: params[:line_item_id])` -- if nil it will simply return a new object.

Answer (score 0):

If each LineItem record is being stored in the database after each form submit, you would handle this in the controller action that is the target of the submit. Something like

```
line_item = LineItem.where(product:params[:product_id], cart_id:session[:cart_id]).first

if line_item
  line_item.update_attributes(quantity: line_item.quantity + params[:quantity].to_i)
else
  LineItem.create(.... #existing code
end
```